# Knex typing with joins and select statement provides a strange type

Tags: javascript, typescript, knex.js

When I provide just a join statement and a blanket select statement knex correctly gives the typing:

```
type t = {
    id: number,
    status: string,
}
type u = {
    id: number,
    name: string
}

const relations = await dbObject<t>('relation')
    .leftJoin<u>('contact_person', 'contact_person.id', 'relation.administrative_contact')
    .select();
// relations is now correctly of type `t & u)[]`
```

The typing is in this case correct and expected.

However when I add some more correctness and specify what I wish to select:

```
type t = {
    id: number,
    status: string,
}
type u = {
    id: number,
    name: string
}

const relations = await dbObject<t>('relation')
    .leftJoin<u>('contact_person', 'contact_person.id', 'relation.administrative_contact')
    .select(['t.id', 't.status', 'u.name']);
// type is now any[][]
```

The typing is now `any` type, which is no totally unexpected. I hope it to use some form of `Pick`, but I think the typing isn't clever enough to mark dots in the array. But more strange the typing is now an array-of-arrays. Which is totally not the correct type and wrong?

What am I doing wrong, why does this happen?

Comment: TypeScript support in Knex is relatively primitive. It doesn't peek into your db schema to ascertain column types for example. It has no idea of the types of `t.id`, `t.status` etc…

Comment: @MichelFloyd yes but that's why we provide the actual types with generics.

Comment: Like I said, it's primitive and that may include buggy - *any[][]* should clearly not be possible.